# Search across multiple Price Ranges

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

We've recently converted an old stored procedure from dynamic SQL to straight SQL.  It is a search engine and we had users entering in strings of values.

So they may want to search across multiple order number so they'll enter

```
111,222-3,444-0
```

We'll process that string into rows in a table value and then JOIN that table to our main orders table to return the rows.

The problem is that one of the choices they have it so search across multiple ranges in price.  So they'll choose the Invoice Totals choice and enter

```
10-25,100-125,200-300
```

What they're asking for is to return orders with invoices that have a total between $10 and $25 OR between $100 and $125 OR between $200 and $300.

I'm not sure how to handle this.  When they're searching string text we just parse the list into FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL statements that we pass into a CONTAINSTABLE call to our FTI.

Any suggestions to get from

```
10-25,100-125,200-300
```

to

```
WHERE InvoiceTotal BETWEEN  10 AND  25
   OR InvoiceTotal BETWEEN 100 and 125
   OR InvoiceTotal BETWEEN 200 and 300
```

Or, something functionally similar without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Might be easiest to redesign the user interface to provide multiple input fields instead of forcing the back end to support variations of input

Comment: It could be done using a couple of string splitting functions (unfortunately, not the built in one since you need to preserve the order in the second split), but I suspect an easier thing to do is to either use dynamic SQL, or if possible, change the stored procedure to accept a table valued parameter with rows containing `From` and `To` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of cross apply and the sql server sting splitter function to filter your data based on the user’s criteria. The following example demonstrates the concept:

```
DECLARE @filter NVARCHAR(1000) = '10-25,100-125,500,200-300';

;WITH CTE_RangeComparisons
AS
(
    -- Use string split function to get input ranges
    SELECT      [value]
                ,(
                    -- If string contain the ‘-‘ character then we know we have a high limit and low limit specified otherwise we assume a single value.
                    CASE 
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('-',[value])  > 0 THEN CAST(LEFT([value], (CHARINDEX('-',[value]) - 1)) AS FLOAT) 
                        ELSE CAST([value] AS FLOAT)
                    END
                 ) AS LowRange
                ,(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('-',[value])  > 0 THEN CAST(RIGHT([value], LEN([value]) - (CHARINDEX('-',[value]))) AS FLOAT)
                        ELSE CAST([value] AS FLOAT)
                    END
                ) AS HighRange
    FROM        string_split(@filter, ',')
)
SELECT      D.*
FROM        [YourDataTable] D
CROSS APPLY (
                -- Use cross apply to filter data on the ranges identified.
                SELECT  1 [Match] -- Selected values here does not matter we are only interested in filtering the parent table.
                FROM    CTE_RangeComparisons R
                WHERE   D.InvoiceTotal >= R.LowRange AND D.InvoiceTotal <= R.HighRange
            ) Ranges
```